# CSS Break overflow words into new line

Tags: html, css

I want to break the words "TEST SUBSCRIBE AND UNSUBSCRIBE" into two lines since the space is not enough to show.

[ScreenShot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VmuSF.png)

```
<div class="activity-details-data">
    Subject Line:
    <br>
    TEST SUBSCRIBE AND UNSUBSCRIBE
</div>
```

I searched other solutions and tried to add `overflow-wrap: break-word;` into the div, but it does not work.. Can I get some help?

Thanks!

Comment: Can you supply more of your applicable code? divs automatically word-wrap when they are cut off, but it looks like something may be absolutely positioned over it and thus is not shrinking the div. Not enough info.

Comment: The text should break automatically unless there is something you haven't told us. - https://codepen.io/Paulie-D/pen/oNNVjKo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to do this you can make width like 150pc to you div and css to the class activity-details-data word-wrap: break-word;

```
<style>
div {
width: 150px; 
border: 1px solid #000000;
}

.activity-details-data {
 word-wrap: break-word;
 }
 </style>


 <div class="activity-details-data">
 Subject Line:
 <br>
 TEST SUBSCRIBE AND UNSUBSCRIBE
 </div>
```